# Select item in join table where multiple sets of conditions need to be met for each link

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a structure setup where conditions can have multiple values (OR claused) and all conditions must be met (AND clause), the amount of conditions is dynamic and can increase or decrease with each query.

I want to perform a lookup on the join table of **Items** and **Condition_Values** (items_values) where an Item meets all the conditions.  The link itself is from **Items** to **Condition_Value** and I am preformatting the SQL to group condition_value_ids into proper claused groups like so:

```
(1 OR 5 OR 6 OR 9), (2 OR 10 OR 15), (9 OR 22 OR 33)
```

to be ANDed together at some point.

I am looking for a way to make SQL query that selects a distinct **Item_Id** where all conditions are met on it being linked to at least one of the **condition_value_ids** in each group.

So a table like so:

```
ITEM_ID              CONDITION_VALUE_ID
  1                            1
  1                            5
  1                            10
  1                            22
  1                            33

  2                            5
  2                            9
  2                            55

  3                            9
  3                            15
  3                            22
```

Would return me ItemS with IDs 1 and 3 (since items 1/3 matched at least 1 condition_value_id link in each condition group, 2 does not have at least 1 match in every group).  My best guess would be something of a gigantic mess of inner statements doing a check like

```
SELECT * FROM items_values 
   WHERE EXISTS(
       SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM items_values WHERE condition_value_id IN (1, 5, 6, 9))
   ) AND
      .....
```

Alternatively, I could take a flat list of condition_value_ids GROUP BY with item_id and do the search manually in PHP, but that seems excessive to collect every item, every search.

Any suggestions in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

***EDIT***

Something like this (Modified version of what they have below):

```
SELECT ITEM_ID,GROUP_CONCAT(CONDITION_VALUE_ID) AS VALUE_IDS, COUNT(CONDITION_VALUE_ID) FROM TEST
GROUP BY ITEM_ID
HAVING COUNT(CONDITION_VALUE_ID) > 1;
```

And then doing a LIKE on each VALUE_IDS would be possible, or just doing in_array checks to match each condition in PHP, but I would prefer if it could be done inside the query.

Comment: Which is it - MySQL or SQLServer?

Comment: @OGHaza sorry didnt realize it tagged both, it is MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a806a/7).

Are you looking for a solution presented by the query or something else.

My query is:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID,
    CONDITION_VALUE_ID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ITEM_ID) AS COMMON_ITEM_ID,
    COUNT(CONDITION_VALUE_ID) 
FROM ITEMS_VALUES
GROUP BY CONDITION_VALUE_ID
HAVING COUNT(CONDITION_VALUE_ID) > 1;
```

If your requirement is something else, please make me understand.

Comment: preferably a solution by the query where it would return a list of item IDs.  The condition for an item to be selected would be that it contained at least 1 condition_value_id from each group of values.  In the schema above that means items 1 and 3 would be returned, but not 2, since it does not have one match in each group

Comment: by group here do you mean these three arrays (1,5,10,22,33) , (5,9,55), (9,15,22) in this case??

Comment: yeah in this case there would be three arrays of condition_value_ids - an Item would need to have at least one row with a condition_value_id exist for each array

Comment: Hey..isn't 2 i.e. (5,9,55) having a match in both the arrays?

Comment: Sorry @Neels, the conditions mentioned in my post were (1, 5, 6, 9), (2, 10 , 15), (9, 22, 33). In the case you mentioned, yes it would.

Comment: it does not appear to be.  You have the correct data set inside your SQL fiddle, and it is matching 1 and 2, not 1 and 3.  Also it doesnt appear to be taking into account the 3 separate arrays as ANDed conditions